# What are the extra letters in wikipedia image URL's and how to determine them?

Tags: javascript, wikipedia

I've noticed with all the wikipedia URL's there are some additional parts (usually 1 character and 2 characters separated by a '/' like in the example below) that don't seem to depend on anything.

Specifically, I am using javascript and trying to randomly acquire pokemon sprites from the online pokemon-wikipedia-equivalent. I have the example below, in the first URL, I can 'calculate' this (Pichu is a pokemon, with index=172). But, in javascript, when when I set my image source to this, the image can't be set (because despite the suffix, this is a webpage, not an image). However, the second url is an actual image, but it has this extra "b/b9" and I can't seem to figure out where that comes from or how to determine it.

So my question is: What do these mean? and how can I determine them?

https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/File:172Pichu.png
https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/b/b9/172Pichu.png

I asked the question about wikipedia since every image's URL follows the same pattern. Here's a wikipedia example:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Westminstpalace.jpg
and https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Westminstpalace.jpg with extra characters '3/39'

Comment: I bet the easiest would he extracting the img source out of the preview page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two numbers are part of a [hash code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) to help with the storage of the image file on the servers.

You cannot directly calculate these numbers if you don't already have the image. You will have to parse the HTML of the preview page to find the correct URL for the image.

In the case of https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Westminstpalace.jpg, the HTML code will somewhere contain the text

```
<img alt="File:Westminstpalace.jpg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Westminstpalace.jpg" width="400" height="300" ... />
```

You will need to find this text and extract the `src` attribute.

Comment: parse what html? what's the relation?

Comment: I added more info